# Error when using JavaScript method .push() in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Am trying to use .push() to add a string on an array but it's printing out on the console, my string thrice.

````
function filterWords(words: string[]): string[] {
  const values: Array<Line> = [];
  const filtered = words.filter(word => {
    if (word.length > 5) {
      values.push("add")
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
  return values;
}

const words = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'da', 'elderberry'];
const filteredWords = filterWords(words);
console.log(filteredWords);```
````

```
Output: [ 'add', 'add', 'add' ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the end goal is here. Since 3 words in the `words` array is longer than 5 characters, `'add'` will be pushed onto the `values` array 3 times.

Comment: @adamius am not getting as to why the 3 times yet my values array is empty

Comment: You pushed the string `'add'` to the array `values`, and you didn't push anything else to that array, and then you returned that array. Of course it only contains the string `'add'`.

Answer (score 1):

this is not how the `filter` function works. learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) :

```
const filtered = words.filter(word => word.length > 5);
console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: I know how to filter but now it  gets tricky where I want to use the push() method

Comment: your code is supposed to work  in `.forEach` or `.map` **but without the `else` statement**. in `.filter` we check the condition and if it's `true` the `item` is pushed to the `array` that will be returned at the end of the function